# The subjunctive mood or not?

Tags: mood

I have found this sentence in a dictionary.

**Section 17 provides that all decisions must be circulated in writing.**

Do you think it can be reworded like this?

**Section 17 provides that all decisions be circulated in writing.** SUBJUNCTIVE
or like this
**Section 17 provides that all decisions are to be circulated in writing.** INDICATIVE

Comment: It depends on what you want to communicate: can you expand on that?

Comment: I am just asking which option is correct.

Comment: Or this? [English subjunctive: an imposition from Latin?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43399/english-subjunctive-an-imposition-from-latin/43423#43423) (All your variants are grammatical, as is the alternative periphrastic 'should be' version. Note that 'provides that' is jargonistic and may not be transparent to the general reader.